# Sound 2.1 not working on 14.04

Tags: pulseaudio

I have an Inspiron 17R SE 7720, with Ubuntu 14.04 installed, and I want to enable 2.1 audio.

The OS is installed as is, without changes. However, my subwoofer isn't working.

And not working the multimedia buttons on keyboard to change volume and mute.

I tried to solve the problem myself, and used all the information about a similar issue, but nothing has helped.

Here is some additional information:

```
lspci | grep -i "audio device"
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: IDT 92HD91BXX
Codec: Intel PantherPoint HDMI
```

---

```
pulseaudio --dump-conf 
### Прочитать из файла конфигурации: /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ###
daemonize = no
fail = yes
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 5
allow-module-loading = yes
allow-exit = yes
use-pid-file = yes
system-instance = no
local-server-type = user
cpu-limit = no
enable-shm = yes
flat-volumes = no
lock-memory = no
exit-idle-time = 20
scache-idle-time = 20
dl-search-path = /usr/lib/pulse-4.0/modules
default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-default-script-file = yes
log-target = auto
log-level = notice
resample-method = speex-float-1
enable-remixing = yes
enable-lfe-remixing = no
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 44100
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
default-fragments = 8
default-fragment-size-msec = 10
enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
shm-size-bytes = 0
log-meta = no
log-time = no
log-backtrace = 0
rlimit-fsize = -1
rlimit-data = -1
rlimit-stack = -1
rlimit-core = -1
rlimit-rss = -1
rlimit-as = -1
rlimit-nproc = -1
rlimit-nofile = 256
rlimit-memlock = -1
rlimit-locks = -1
rlimit-sigpending = -1
rlimit-msgqueue = -1
rlimit-nice = 31
rlimit-rtprio = 9
rlimit-rttime = 1000000
```

Comment: Did it work in 13.10 or 12.04?

Comment: I have not installed this version on this laptop. It is necessary to determine unconnected pins, and create 2.1 analog audio profile, and may be correct /etc/pulse/daemon.conf and /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

Comment: Could you try? If it works then you have a bug.

Comment: It is not the true method to resolve this problem.

Comment: Somebody help me?